# Check cell content exists in inputed string from screen - Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have an excel file with 2 columns as below. I want to check the cell content in Column Name 'CODE1' exists in a string which inputted from the screen.. and then will return the result on screen is Column Name 'RESULT'

```
import pandas as pd
import getpass
import random

path_to_csv_file = 'C:\\names.xlsx'
code_names_dataframe = pd.read_excel(path_to_csv_file) 
code_names_dictionary = code_names_dataframe.to_dict(orient='records')

user_response = input()
user_response=user_response.lower()
while True:  
    name = None
    username = user_response
    for code_name in code_names_dictionary:
        if username.contains(code_name['CODE1']).any():
            name = code_name['RESULT']       
    if name is not None:    
        break       
    else:
        print('Not Correct')
        break
print(name)
```

The Excel Format as below :

```
CODE1       RESULT

excel       OK. Excel
apple       OK. Apple
```

I want to when user input string on screen as 'I want to receive an apple'... then the result will return on screen is 'OK. Apple'

When I run code , it show error as below :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Chatbot - ReadData\ExcelCSV.py", line 58, in <module>
    mainmenu()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Chatbot - ReadData\ExcelCSV.py", line 49, in mainmenu
    if username.contains(code_name['CODE1']).any():
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'contains'
```

Please help me.

Comment: `username` is norma string, not `dataframe` and it doesn't have `.contains()` . Maybe you means `code_name['CODE1'].contains(username)` ? OR maybe `if  code_name['CODE1'] in username:` will work ?

Comment: Hi Bro. I have tried to used 'if code_name['CODE1'] in username:'  but it not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split text into list of words and then you can use `isin()`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
        'CODE': ['excel', 'apple'],
        'RESULT':['OK. Excel', 'OK. Apple']
})

text = 'I want to receive an apple'.lower()
words = text.split(' ')

mask = df['CODE'].isin(words)

print( mask )

print( df[ mask ] )

if mask.any():
    name = df[mask]['RESULT'].iloc[0]
else:
    name = None
print('Name:', name)
```

Result

```
# mask
0    False
1     True
Name: CODE, dtype: bool

# df[mask]    
    CODE     RESULT
1  apple  OK. Apple

Name: OK. Apple
```

---

**EDIT:** other method

```
mask = df['CODE'].apply(lambda x: x.lower() in text.lower())
```

Code

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
        'CODE': ['excel file', 'apple'],
        'RESULT':['OK. Excel', 'OK. Apple']
})

text = 'I have excel file on the PC'

mask = df['CODE'].apply(lambda x: x.lower() in text.lower())

print( mask )

print( df[ mask ] )

if mask.any():
    name = df[mask]['RESULT'].iloc[0]
else:
    name = None
print('Name:', name)
```

Result

```
# mask
0     True
1    False
Name: CODE, dtype: bool

# df[mask]
         CODE     RESULT
0  excel file  OK. Excel

Name: OK. Excel
```

Comment: Thanks you bro! But how to use pandas to read data from columns in excel file instead of declare DataFrame .

Comment: Thanks you so much bro. How to edit command if I want the command as : df = pd.DataFrame({
        'CODE1': ['Excel', 'Apple'],
        'RESULT':['OK. Wait me']})

Comment: I want when user input on the screen 'Excel' or 'Apple'..... then the result will return only one 'OK. Wait me' ….. Thanks you very much!

Comment: Hi Bro. 
I want to include backspace while checking str. How to do that ? I want to check 'Excel file' is substring of 'I have excel file on the PC' … I do not want to Split backspace out of string while checking .

Comment: `mask = df['CODE'].apply(lambda x: x.lower() in 'I have excel file on the PC'.lower())`

Comment: Hi Bro. I do not want to split space character in str while checking... because I need compare 2 str ( include backspace )

Comment: Thanks you Bro... I have used this command   "excelmatch = code_names_dataframe['EXCEL'].apply(lambda x: True if x.lower() in excel.lower() else False)"

Comment: code `x.lower() in excel.lower()` already gives `True` or `Flase` - so there is no need to add `True if ... else False`